# Proper permissions for "SHOW TABLE STATUS" in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1045

I can insert, update, delete, etc. to a table in my MySQL database but I cannot show the table status. Does anyone know which privilege(s) is needed to do this?

Here is my error message:

```
Access denied for user 'admin459'@'localhost' to database 'sample'
```

Comment: Good question! The manual is completely mute on this. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html#grant-table-privileges

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show.html - the last part plus the user comment indirectly refer SELECT=SHOW, however, if the user able to update/delete/insert, not sure why is blocked from select

Comment: This might be your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6527599/mysql-forgets-who-is-logged-in-command-denied-to-user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minimal (select only) privileges is all I need to get table status.  What version of mysql?

```
grant select on test_dev.districts to td3@localhost identified by 'monkey';
```

then:

```
mysql -pmonkey  -u td3 TAMS_development -e 'show table status;'
```

works.

what does this return for you?

```
show grants for admin459@localhost;
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems odd... even my MySQL users with minimal priveledges can do SHOW TABLE STATUS's on their respective databases.

Can you give an example of the exact syntax you're attempting?

e.g. `SHOW TABLE STATUS IN sample LIKE 'users'`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try another way to view all the information about a particular table,
especially the *column comments* (beside "access denied" during `SHOW TABLE STATUS`):

Access the **INFORMATION_SCHEMA** of the database directly (if you have the
SELECT-privilege).

For Information about the table itself (normally one tupel):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    information_schema.tables
WHERE
        table_schema = 'my_db'
    AND table_name = 'my_tab_name'
;
```

For Information about columns:

```
SELECT 
      table_name
    , column_name
    , column_comment
FROM
    information_schema.columns
WHERE
        table_schema = 'my_db'
    AND table_name = 'my_tab_name'
;
```

It just worked for me.

Furthermore a

```
SHOW TABLES FROM information_schema;
```

offers you all the available "information-tables".

And/or use a shortcut, as mentioned in "[Show Comment of Fields FROM Mysql Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404051/show-comment-of-fields-from-mysql-table)"

```
SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM my_tab_name;
```