# Show Comment of Fields FROM Mysql Table

Tags: mysql

`SHOW COLUMNS FROM <tablename>` gives all the information of the columns in a table, except `Comments`.

How to extract `Comments` information? I know the way to extract the information from INFORMATION SCHEMA, but how to combine the result in  a single result set?

Answer (score 161, accepted):

You can use the query

```
SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM <tablename>
```

If you don't want to use `information_schema`.

Comment: WOW, so simple, You can't even imagine what a dangerous looking query I was building at the moment.

Comment: @nick, by the way, can i modify the result set as per the need. Like I dont want `Collation`, `Privileges`, `Key`, `Extra`

Comment: Unluckily show syntax is not flexible like information_schema. If you want to choose only some fields you have to query information_schema.columns table

Comment: If you tell us exactly what you need I'll try to help you with pleasure.

Comment: Thank you for your concern, I need to know one more thing, is it slower using information_schema?

Comment: I'm not skilled like a lot of users of SO.AFAIK, for my little experience, information_schema is slower than show statements. However it depends on the kind of query you run on it. There are a lot of things that you can't do using show, so you're forced to rely on information_schema .

Answer (score 19):

```
select `column_name`, `column_type`, `column_default`, `column_comment`
from `information_schema`.`COLUMNS` 
where `table_name` = 'table-name' 
and `table_schema` = 'db-name';
```

Comment: Nicola's answer is much simpler. Does this add anything?

Comment: If your use case doesn't require all of the columns from the `SHOW FULL` command, then yes, it adds something.

Answer (score 6):

In case you want to get the table comments instead :

```
SELECT table_comment
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE table_name = 'my_table' and 
      table_schema = 'my_database'
```

Comment: `table_comment` column of `tables` table in `information_schema` database keeps comments for **tables** and not for columns; but thanks for pointing out it in here too as it is relevant.

Comment: it'd be also noteworthy to add that (the default) `table_comment` for [tag:views] are `VIEW`; and that table comments are defined in the `create table` statement; and unlike `show full columns`, the `show full tables` statement do not display comments, for [tag:table]s, unfortunately.

Comment: `SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM yourSchemaName WHERE Name = 'yourTableName';` - same output, different syntax.

Comment: Nicola's answer is much simpler. Is this advantageous to that method in some way? There is more information in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` probably, I'd think.

Comment: Thanks for this. I used it as a basis to get all the descriptions of the tables within a database:
`SELECT table_name,table_comment
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE table_schema = 'my_database'
AND table_type != "VIEW"
ORDER BY table_name;`