# mysql forgets who is logged in: command denied to user ''@'%'

Tags: mysql

Running `show grants;` indicates that I am logged in as a user with all privileges on a database.

Running `show table status;` results in an error.  And the error does not show the username I am logged in as!

It's as if, for this command, mysql forgets who I am.  Other select statements work fine.  Can anyone explain this?  How to fix?  Thanks.

```
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 2
Server version: 5.5.13-log Source distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2010, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> show grants;
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for php@localhost                                                                                            |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'php'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*8F5FF90079BC601F8EA7C148475658E65A0C029D' |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `sunflower_work`.* TO 'php'@'localhost'                                                     |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `news_demo`.* TO 'php'@'localhost'                                                          |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `news_base`.* TO 'php'@'localhost'                                                          |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show table status from sunflower_work;
ERROR 1143 (42000): SELECT command denied to user ''@'%' for column 'uid' in table 'users'
mysql>
```

update... as suggested by Tomalak, I deleted the user and recreated with fuller privileges and no password.  Still the problem persists.  Now it looks like this:

```
mysql> show grants;
+--------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for php@localhost                         |
+--------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'php'@'localhost' |
+--------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show table status;
ERROR 1143 (42000): SELECT command denied to user ''@'%' for column 'uid' in table 'users'
mysql>
```

Comment: There may be two problems: a faulty error message and misbehaving privileges. To solve the latter issue, can you delete all the `GRANT`s and re-add just the first one, _not_ using `IDENTIFIED BY` (let the actual user record contain the password)? I wonder whether there's a conflict in that list.

Comment: @tomalak geret'kal: If you google the error message, you'd know that 1143 is a typo -- it's 1142 like the 16+ other questions...

Comment: @OMGPonies: If you bother to [look it up](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-server.html), you'll see that 1142 does not contain column information, whereas 1143 does. Why would the OP have made a typo in a blatantly copy/pasted output?

Comment: @tomalak geret'kal: Then fix the rest ;)

Comment: @OMGPonies: What "rest"?

Comment: TG is correct that I copied and pasted the text.  So any "typo" is coming from mysql, not my keyboard.

Comment: Trying to "delete all the GRANTs and re-add just the first one" as suggested by TG.  I can't figure it out!  These commands have no effect...

Comment: These are the commands that have no effect...

Comment: This comment form is infuriating!  this command affects 0 rows, [code]REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* FROM 'php'@'localhost';[/code] and likewise this [code]REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* FROM 'php'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*8F5FF90079BC601F8EA7C148475658E65A0C029D';[/code]

Comment: I've tested this on two arch linux boxes now, using the same mysql user name, grants, password.  One one box the `show table status` works fine, on the other I get this error.  So I'm not sure if the problem is how mysql is configured or what.  Any help getting better messages from mysql would be appreciated.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The issue is probably that you have VIEWS in your database. The views are probably created with specific rights.

As you can tell by your error message, it complains about a *different* user than the one you are logged in is. This is because for a view you can specify how to determine what rights the view has to look at data.

When you go to your database, try typing:

```
SHOW FULL TABLES IN sunflower_work WHERE TABLE_TYPE NOT LIKE '%table%';
```

Then you may wish to look into the rights of the specific views that are there.

Comment: Oh, so the issue is not that MySQL 'forgets' the user that is logged in. The issue is that MySQL uses views that have to behave as a different user.

Comment: and same buggy behavior can happen with triggers.

Comment: it's not really buggy; it's more that the error messages are unclear.

Comment: Aljakim: for me I call it buggy because usually I'm hit after a dump/restore on another database and I don't like to have the triggers and views broken because the users are different (or have diffrent restrictions on hosts).

Comment: It turns out, I could not even dump my database, using `mysqldump --opt sunflower_work`.  However the mysqldump presented an error that was much more helpful.  (I don't have it handy to paste here).

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, an error message that lousy is a bug.  I mean the error specifically mentions a table which is not a view!  Also, just the fact that views can break fundamental features if you delete a user... that's broken.

Comment: "The views are probably created with specific rights" - Is there a way to create my views in a more robust way?  Also thanks for the answer above.

Comment: Pff, I am always fighting with views because of the way the rights work. I think I have the same issues that Regilero does, we just name them differently.

You can do two things to make it more robust:
1. - use `DEFINER=CURRENT_USER`, this stops the issues with unknown users/rights.
2. - use `SQL SECURITY INVOKER`, this means it is run with the rights of the invoker. Now, this may not be what you want! Many people use views to give limited access to data, so you need the rights of the definer.

Comment: @Dave: '... break fundamental features if you delete a user...', if you specify the view to use the security rights of a specific user it makes sense that it breaks the view if that user is deleted. I don't think that's a bug or bad design.

You do have a point that the error messages are really really bad in this case.

Comment: Oh, finally, the link to the manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html this gives specifics on setting the `DEFINER`, etc...

Answer (score 6):

The answers here helped me with my specific problem. Many thanks! A view was the culprit as described above.

I got into trouble because the database in question was created from a backup of a remote database which had different users. The 'broken' view was 'defined' by a user I didn't have locally. Even root was unable to run the crashing query.

Changed the view's 'DEFINER' to a valid local user and the problem was solved!

```
ALTER 
DEFINER = 'a_valid_user'@'localhost' 
VIEW my_view
AS 
SELECT .....
```

[Check out ALTER VIEW documentation for MySQL 5.5](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-view.html)

Many thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Take schema backup before proceeding.

If you just imported a dump file in mysql, delete that import and related schema and start again.

open the dump file in a text editor and delete all lines with the following content
/*! ~~~~ DEFINER='root' @'%' SQL SECURITY DEFINER */

~ Represents a random number generated by workbench during export

This solution is a quick fix and intended for development environments only.