# phpMyAdmin doesn't show table list for database that definitely has tables

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp

I have a website, written in php, using a MySQL database. After buying a new laptop (Windows 7), I downloaded WAMP 2.2, with MySQL 5.5.20, PHP 5.3.10 and phpMyAdmin 3.4.10.1. I exported the whole database from the live website and imported it into my wamp environment, using MySQL console.

phpMyAdmin lists the database, but says there are no tables in it. Yet, the websites workss within the WAMP environment. Further, if I perform an SQL "SHOW TABLES" within phpMyAdmin, it displays the tables.

I'm completely puzzled as to why these tables aren't listed in the leftmost column of phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Caching issue maybe? Did you clear the browser cache?

Answer (score 11):

I was having a similar problem. Through some digging I found that phpMyAdmin's table list was failing on this query:

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM `database`;
```

And this was the error message:

```
ERROR 1143 (42000): SELECT command denied to user ''@'localhost'
 for column `column` in table `table`
```

Which led me to this SO question: [mysql forgets who is logged in: command denied to user ''@'%'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6527599/mysql-forgets-who-is-logged-in-command-denied-to-user)

Which led me to the conclusion that one of the views that I loaded into the database has privileges that are conflicting. Indeed, when I looked at the SQL dump I was loading the database from, I found the culprit:

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`someotheruser`@`localhost` ..
```

Where `someotheruser` did not exist in my local MySQL. I changed it to the following:

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` ..
```

And reloaded the view, and everything is now working properly.

Comment: if "UNDEFINED" is considered as root, what about security vulnerability?

Comment: if we define root as user instead of specific user, what about security vulnerability?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with Definer if you have any view in the database.

Just drop the Views and it should work, or you can open the exported database file in Notepad and change Definer to root.

Answer (score -4):

Just to help someone else, in the phpMyAdmin, in config.inc.php, change this:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = '**mysqli**';
```

to this:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = '**mysql**';
```

Comment: Don't, you want to use the `mysqli`, a lot faster and more reliable