# phpmyadmin No tables found in database

Tags: mysql, permissions, phpmyadmin, backup

I'm sure that there are a lot of people facing my problem; I had copied the data folder inside mysql on the hard disk, then format my computer, then I have pasted the data folder, 
then all databases shows the number of tables, and when I make query show tables.

Its showing all tables inside database, but when I try to access the tables, it's showing table does not exist?

Please, I have a lot of projects, can any body help me? 
Note that there was no password on the previous version and the user was root as now.
Please help.

Comment: I had the same problem and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9877814/phpmyadmin-doesnt-show-table-list-for-database-that-definitely-has-tables saved my day

Answer (score 1):

I did not move any database file, but I had the same error message *"No tables found in database"* within **PhpMyAdmin**. But I could access the database by sql. I found out that it was caused by the browser. Using another browser or a private window helped. Did not try a restart or deleting cache so far.

Answer (score 1):

If your **phpMyAdmin** no longer sees any tables in any of your local databases, that is because permissions change away from **mysql.mysql** on any database directory under **/var/lib/mysql** to, say, **root.root** (most probably).

You will have to change the owner from **root.root** to **mysql.mysql**, to do this, youâll need root access and putty. Key in this command:

```
chown -R mysql.mysql /var/lib/mysql/
```

Comment: Not sure, why this answer has been downvoted before. Almost five years later, this was exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a duplicate: [MySQL Table does not exist error, but it does exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260546/mysql-table-does-not-exist-error-but-it-does-exist)

But moving files is not the way to save the database,best way is the export,import.

Comment: thank you thank you thank you , the link is the exact what i wanted .