# Create View from another view in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a view from another view from php and im not getting any error but it simple does not create a view. I can manually create view from another in the mysql console but not from php. Any idea where I am going wrong?

```
function createTransaction_file($db,$file_id){

      $sql = "CREATE VIEW transaction_file AS SELECT context,transaction_type,starttime,stoptime,stoptime - starttime AS runtime,correlator,parent_correlator,iteration FROM transactions WHERE file_id =" . $file_id . " ORDER BY starttime" ;

      //echo $sql;

      if($stmt = $db->prepare($sql)){

         /* execute query */
         $stmt->execute();
      }else{

       echo "File id is ". $file_id;

       echo "Error code ({$db->errno}): {$db->error}";

       die("Could not create transaction_iter view");
    }

    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();

}

function createTransaction_iter($db,$iteration){

      $sql = "CREATE VIEW transaction_iter AS SELECT context,transaction_type,starttime,stoptime,stoptime - starttime AS runtime,correlator,parent_correlator,iteration FROM transaction_file WHERE iteration = ".$iteration." LIMIT 500;" ;

      //echo $sql;

      if($stmt = $db->prepare($sql)){

         /* execute query */
         $stmt->execute();


      }else{

       echo "File id is ". $file_id;

       echo "Error code ({$db->errno}): {$db->error}";

       die("Could not create transaction_iter view");
    }

    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();

}

createTransaction_file($db,$file_id);
createTransaction_iter($db,$iteration);
```

Comment: Does the connection from code have same credentials as console?  Just a permission issue w/ CREATE VIEW?  Those echo statements get you any info on the error?

Comment: Nope no error as the prepare statement works and it does not enter the else loop

Comment: Hmm, your else is on the prepare.  Not the execute.  Check the return value of the `execute` statement.  Are you confusing a try/catch  block with that if/else?

Comment: The first view is created without any issues. It is the second view which is not getting created.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to check the return value? Is it just echo $stmt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are simply not getting the details of the error back.  Again, that if/else block is not what you meant to do I believe. Try something like this:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

if (! $stmt->execute()) {
    $arr = $stmt->errorInfo();
    print_r($arr);
}
```

**UPDATE:** So as expected that error message suggests a lack of required permissions for your user.  I'm guessing your views were created with different rights.  Here is a similar SO posting: [mysql forgets who is logged in: command denied to user ''@'%'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6527599/mysql-forgets-who-is-logged-in-command-denied-to-user) that discusses how you can get insight into the rights of those views/tables.

Comment: I am getting this error in php error log .. PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::errorInfo()

Comment: I used $stmt->error and got this error -> Error: ANY command denied to user 'matryoshka'@'localhost' for column 'context' in table 'transaction_file'.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me find the error. Could you please help me fix the error

Comment: I could not fix the error with links provided but Im using temporary tables to get the work done. Thanks again for your answer.